# c++ function overloading, what are the exact steps

Tags: c++, overloading

I was reading about function overloading and found the following:

> The compiler lists all functions with the same name and the same
>   number of arguments, and then it starts looking for a function using
>   the following rules by a fixed order and stops when there is a match.
>
> 1) A function that exactly has the same arguments' types as the call
>   to it.
>
> 2) bool-> int char->int float-> double... (-> means is converted to)
>
> 3) int-> double, double->int... (-> means is converted to)

**For example:**

```
void foo(int x)
{
    return;
}

foo(True);//will trigger step 2.
```

could someone elaborate number 2 and 3? and add the full list?

Comment: Where is this description from? For starters, it’s wrong. Here’s a better description: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Comment: I translated it from another language, why it's wrong?

Comment: "starts looking for a function using the following rules by a fixed order and stops when there is a match" is wrong. It first finds the set of viable functions, then it ranks them. If there is an unambiguous best, that's the call, otherwise it's ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

*1) A function that exactly has the same arguments' types as the call to it*

So if im trying to call `foo(1)` it will first try to find any function named `foo` that takes a single argument of type `int`.

*2) bool-> int char->int float-> double... (-> means is converted to)*

So if i do `foo(True)` and it doesnt find anything in step 1, it will try converting `True` to an `int` and will do step 1) again

*3) int-> double, double->int... (-> means is converted to)*

If the 2) step doesnt find any suitable functions, it will try converting any `int` arguments into `double`, and so on.

Comment: but what about the full list for number 2 and 3?